# Scanner errors with array list

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am creating a program which takes a file name as a parameter and checks for palindromes in the text. The program will also replace letters based on a users input or remove a word based on the users input. For some reason, the scanner under

```
public void letter

and 

public void word
```

isn't working properly.

This is the error I am receiving after the program runs and the user types in:

```
What would you like to do? Here are your options: 

Press 1 to Print all palindromes 

Press 2 to Replace any letter  

Press 3 to remove all occurences of a word 

Press 4 to exit

2

What letter would you like to remove?

e

What letter would you like to add?

r

[ ]

What would you like to do? Here are your options: 

Press 1 to Print all palindromes 

Press 2 to Replace any letter  

Press 3 to remove all occurences of a word 

Press 4 to exit
```

This is the error which I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at Homework6.main(Homework6.java:28)**
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

static ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test2 = new Test();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            strings.add(scanner.next());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

            //ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(strings);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? Here are your options: \nPress 1 to Print all palindromes \nPress 2 to Replace any letter  \nPress 3 to remove all occurences of a word \nPress 4 to exit\n");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String command = s.next();

        if (command.equals("1")) {
            test2.pal();
        } else if (command.equals("2")) {
            test2.letter();
        } else if (command.equals("3")) {
            test2.word();
        } else if (command.equals("4")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public void pal() {
    int a;
    int c;
    // boolean isPalindrome() ;

    for (a = 0; a < strings.size(); a++) {
        String replace = strings.get(a);
        replace = replace.replaceAll("[.,']", "");
    }

    for (c = 0; c < strings.size(); c++) {
        boolean pal = PalindromeChecker.isPalindrome(strings.get(c));

        if (true) {
            System.out.print(strings.get(c));
        }
    }
}

public void letter() {

    int b;
    Scanner replaceLetter = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What letter would you like to remove?");
    String badLetter = replaceLetter.next();
    System.out.println("What letter would you like to add?");
    String newLetter = replaceLetter.next();
    for (b = 0; b < strings.size(); b++) {
        String replaceVowels = strings.get(b);
        replaceVowels = replaceVowels.replace("badVowel", "newVowel");
    }
    replaceLetter.close();

    System.out.print(strings);
}

public void word() {

    Scanner removeWord = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What word would you like to remove?");
    String word = removeWord.next();
    strings.remove(word);
    removeWord.close();
    System.out.print(strings);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove these lines .. it will work...

```
     replaceLetter.close ();
     removeWord.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @TheLostMind's answer, the problem is that when you call [`Scanner#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29), it will also close the underlying stream if it implements the `Closeable` interface. Taken from the docs:

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying
>   readable also implements the Closeable interface then **the readable's
>   close method will be invoked**. If this scanner is already closed then
>   invoking this method will have no effect.

Thus, in your `letter()` and `word()` functions, when you call close, **it will also close System.in**. So, when you try to use a `Scanner` to read from `System.in` again, there's nothing left to read, and you get the `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){}
```

and `scanner.nextLine`

instead of `hasNext()` & `next()`.

And if you are using `java7` then it would be best to code like this:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file)) {

}
```

It will automatically close `Scanner` and is safe from any type of `leak`